# How can I replace the onclick action (with regex) using javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use jQuery to replace part of the `onclick` property / attribute? In the example below I would like to replace `delete_image` with `do_delete_image`:

#### Sample HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="delete_image(1234)" >Delete Image</a>
```

#### My Attempt

```
jQuery('a').each(function(){
    var action = $(this).prop('onclick').replace('delete_image','do_delete_image');
    $(this).prop('onclick',action);
});
```

#### Error

Google chrome is throwing this error:

> TypeError: Object function onclick(event) { delete_image(1234);return false; } has no method 'replace'

How can I make this work? ps: This is a bookmarklet set to work with someone else's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` is a property representing the function that handles the `click` event. To get and set the actual content, use `attr` instead of `prop`.

Alternatively, consider replacing `delete_image` with `do_delete_image`, for example:

```
window.delete_image = window.do_delete_image;
```

You can combine this with closures if you need to wrap the original function.

Comment: not a method to edit the attribute but a slick way to achieve what i wanted. thanks so much! +1

Answer (score 0):

use **$(this).unbind()** to clear handlers on that element and then add new one

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7, this should work...

```
jQuery('a').each(function(){
    $(this).off('click')
        .on('click', do_delete_image);
});
```